# Is "number" not a valid MySQL data type?

Tags: mysql, ddl

```
create table S (SNO text, SNAME text, STATUS number, CITY text)
insert into S values('S1','Smith','20','London')
insert into S values('S2','Jones','10','Paris')
insert into S values('S3','Blake','30','Paris')
insert into S values('S4','Clark','20','London')
insert into S values('S5','Adams','30','Athens')
```

Im having a hard time figuring out why this is not a valid SQL query, I have tried googling for answers but to no avail.

I have tried to query an Sqlite database with JDBC and i have also tried inserting it into phpMyAdmins query field.
This is the error message presented by phpMyAdmin,

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number, CITY text) insert into S values('S1','Smith','20','London') insert int' at line 1`

Comment: The available datatypes are all documented in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html (an dI'm pretty sure you don't want `text` for those columns).

Comment: For many `INSERT` statements it is recommended that you use `TRANSACTION`s

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html for numeric types available for use.

Comment: `NUMBER` is a type in Oracle, maybe MS Access, but not MySQL. There you need something like `INT, FLOAT, DECIMAL()`, probably `INT` for a status column.

Comment: Yes using INT instead of number worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `S` (`SNO` TEXT, `SNAME` TEXT, `STATUS` INT, `CITY` TEXT);

START TRANSACTION;

BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('S1', 'Smith', 20, 'London');
INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('S2', 'Jones', 10, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('S3', 'Blake', 30, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('S4', 'Clark', 20, 'London');
INSERT INTO `S` VALUES ('S5', 'Adams', 30, 'Athens');
COMMIT;
```

Try this one out.

Edits:

- Changed `number` to `INT`
- Added semicolons (As **Gabe** mentioned)
- Added backticks around the table and column names
- Added Transaction (Speeds up `INSERT` queries, optional)
- Removed quotes around the numbers (As **christiandev** mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

The type you were looking for may be `NUMERIC` rather than `NUMBER`. Also, you need to put a semicolon `;` between statements in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `quotes` around the number

```
create table S (SNO text, SNAME text, STATUS number, CITY text)
insert into S values('S1','Smith',20,'London')
```

**EDIT**: From my [`fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb68e/1)

```
CREATE TABLE s
    (
      SNO VARCHAR(35) ,
      SNAME VARCHAR(35) ,
      STATUS INT ,
      CITY VARCHAR(35)
    ) ;
INSERT  INTO s
VALUES  ( 'S1', 'Smith', 20, 'London' ) ;
INSERT  INTO s
VALUES  ( 'S2', 'Jones', 10, 'Paris' )

SELECT  *
FROM    s
```

Also, should `number` be one of these [`types`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)?

Answer (score 0):

`STATUS` is reserved:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/show-table-status.html

Use

```
 create table S (SNO text, SNAME text, `STATUS` int, CITY text)
```

instead